# Jsoup don't get all elemts of website

Tags: jsoup

I wrote some code to use Jsoup like:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(category.getLink()).get();
```

but it got some elements of website not all. I want to get all elements in website, please tell me how I should do?

Comment: Does the website generate content using javascript?

Comment: you need to be a bit more specific. what website is it? how does the html look like? what does Jsoup return? Many things can be the reason: From missing connections to AJAX calls in the site...

Comment: I found problem, like two you said, it can't handle AJAX :). Thank for help

Answer (score 0):

OP finds a solution:

> I found problem, like two you said, it can't handle AJAX :). Thank for help ([Itachi Tensie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2202460/itachi-tensie))